# PHP preg_match expression not matching correct characters

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I'm trying to catch any characters that are not letters, numbers, or .-_ (period, dash, underscore)

My code is

```
return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9.-_]/', $strToFilter);
```

My hope is that it will return false when it find an invalid character. As of now it allows ._ (period and underscore) but does not allow - (dash). It also does not detect characters like /, \, [, ], %, ^, etc as invalid characters.

What is wrong with my expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Regex character classes, you can't match a literal hyphen unless it is:

1. immediately against either bracket,
2. follows the negate caret (`^`), or
3. is escaped using the backslash (`\`)

> The hyphen can be included right after the opening bracket, or right before the closing bracket, or right after the negating caret. Both [-x] and [x-] match an x or a hyphen. [^-x] and [^x-] match any character thas is not an x or a hyphen. This works in all flavors discussed in this tutorial. Hyphens at other positions in character classes where they can't form a range may be interpreted as literals or as errors. Regex flavors are quite inconsistent about this.

[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - See *Metacharacters Inside Character Classes*.

Comment: Immediatly against a bracket or negate caret are not te only solutions. +1 if you add escaping to your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the dash:

```
return !preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9.\-_]/', $strToFilter);
```